# Can FMX on Windows use an OpenGL canvas by default?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to make an FMX app on Windows use an OpenGL canvas by default, instead of the GDI+ canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Firemonkey on Windows uses DirectX, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Set GlobalUseGPUCanvas to True.

[All about FMX Canvas.](https://parnassus.co/firemonkey-canvas-classes-and-a-bugfix-to-speed-up-your-apps/)